# React Native Expo iOS simulator in windows

Tags: iphone, react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I am starting a React Native app and I work on Windows (I do not have any ios devices). How do I know how does my app look and work on iOS devices? Is it even possible to run some kind of simulator in windows that will allow me to render my RN app in an iphone? I have android studio and an android phone so android is covered but I wanted to know how I can do the same for iphones. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running IOS simulator is only possible on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run iOS simulator on Windows.

However:

If you have an actual iPhone connected to the same WiFi network as your PC, then by installing the "Expo Go" app on it you can run and test your app live. It comes with hot-reload (save a file - and iPhone refreshes instantly) and some other very handy features.

You basically execute one command `npx expo start`, scan the QR code on your iPhone and you're good to go.

But yes, you will need an actual iPhone for that unfortunately.